# Issue in passing int16_t and uint8_t values through JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, casting, java-native-interface

I have a struct in C++ that looks like:

```
typedef struct {
  int16_t param1;
  uint8_t param2;
  uint8_t param3;
} Sample;
```

I receive a `vector<Sample>` in JNI and I want to pass this to Java layer.

My java class is:

```
public class JavaSample {
    short mP1;
    short mP2;
    short mP3;

    public JavaSample(short p1, short p2, short p3) {
      mP1 = p1; mP2 = p2; mP3 = p3;
    }
}
```

In Java I have methods:

```
 public ArrayList<Sample> getList() { return new ArrayList<>();}
 public void addSample(ArrayList<Sample> list, short p1, short p2, short p3) 
 { list.add(new Sample(p1, p2, p3));
 }
```

In JNI I first get an empty arraylist using `getList`. Next I loop over the `vector<Sample>` and for every sample i do

```
env->CallVoidMethod(clazzObj, methodId, list, sample.param1, sample.param2, sample.param3);
```

Here `clazzObj` points to my java side class, `methodId` points to `addSample` method and `list` is the initially empty list.

Using the above, when I run the program, it crashes with error like:
`JNI ERROR (app bug): expected jshort but got value of -15007284 as argument 3 to void com.example.MainActivity.addSample(java.util.ArrayList, short, short, short)`

So it seems that it found a garbage value more than the capacity of short for that field. This seems to happen randomly to either of the 3 params (even the `int16_t` which should ideally match short.)
If I use `int` instead of `short` then it does not crash but garbage values get passed on to the java side.
Could anyone suggest what is going on?

Comment: `-15007284` doesn't make sense as a hex value that somehow came from a `uint8_t`.  What are the values of the parameters passed?  And please post the actual code.  Your `sample.p1, sample.p2, sample.p3` code doesn't match the `Sample` structure you posted.

Comment: The negative value did not come from the uint8_t. It is supposed to be 0. But somehow jni is reading garbage value from the address. An example sample value is : -127 0 0. Sorry about the typo. Will correct it.

Comment: I think you're going to have to post more code.  Something is getting corrupted, and it's impossible to tell without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use explicit casting when you make the call:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(clazzObj, methodId, list, (jshort)sample.param1, (jshort)sample.param2, (jshort)sample.param3);
```

The problem is that **CallVoidMethod()** has no information about the expected length of its arguments (beyond **methodId**), and uses the natural length of 1 byte for **sample.param2** and **sample.param3** while the Java method knows that these should be two bytes. As a result, the last parameter interpreted by Java method was garbage.